# How to kill process with pid like Android Studio does?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

In Android Studio. There is a `Terminate Application` button in Logcat. We can use it to kill any debuggable process (not whole package). How can I do this via adb command?

I have tried `adb shell kill` but it requires root permission.

And `adb shell am force-stop` but it killed whole package.

I want to kill a child-process, such as `com.domain.app:push` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill process for specific package as follows:

```
adb shell am kill [--user <USER_ID> | all | current] <PACKAGE>
```

This command doesn't require root permission.

**You can use following commnad to get the pid**

```
adb shell ps | <PACKAGE>
```

Comment: I want to kill process with pid, not package, i have tried adb shell am kill 6719, it doesn't work

Comment: @CaoDongping can you specify package name and the pid which you want to kill?

Comment: its my debug app. package is com.qiyi.video, pid,,,changes every launch, so, just a number, such as 6719